# How to change the mode of Editbox from read mode to edit mode in Xpage?

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, xpages

Actually, I have set true to the property- **Read-Only** in `Xpage` for a particular field.

And I have tried to change its mode to edit in client side javascript. But I am not able to change.
I used the following code...

```
document.getElementById("#{id:read}").readOnly=false;
```

and also

```
dojo.attr("#{id:read}","readOnly",false);
```

Both are failed...

```
(@Trim)
Also in Server side Javascript XSP Code is:      

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" dojoParseOnLoad="true"
dojoTheme="true">
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.Dialog"></xp:dojoModule>
</xp:this.resources>

<div id="dojoTest" dojoType="dijit.Dialog">
<xp:inputText id="field" defaultValue="Hello" readonly="true"></xp:inputText>

<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="field">
        <xp:this.action> <![CDATA[{javascript:getComponent("field").setReadonly(false);}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
<xp:br></xp:br></div>

<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:button value="Show Popup" id="button2">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dijit.byId("dojoTest").show();]]> </xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Not possible in client side script only. You must issue partial refresh which will render editbox differently (span in read mode vs input in edit mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further review, this issue has nothing to do with the field itself: the code included in the question is appropriate to the desired response. Rather, the problem is that the event is defined inside a dijit.Dialog.

When Dojo parses a dialog, it moves the DOM elements to the end of the body for layout reasons. Unfortunately, this also moves it outside of the form. This breaks any server-side events, because the event data no longer gets serialized as part of the form. So in your example, the event fails not because the event code is wrong, but because the event itself is never triggered.

The ideal solution to this is to use the Dialog component from the Extension Library (or 8.5.3 UP1) instead of a passthru div with a specified dojoType. If this is not an option, there is a workaround... add the following component at the bottom of the page:

```
<xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
    var dominoForm = XSP.byId("#{javascript:return view.findScriptCollector().getClientId(facesContext);}");
    dojo.query("div.dijitDialog").forEach(function(eachDialog){
        dojo.place(eachDialog, dominoForm, "last");
    });
});]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

This should cause all parsed dialogs to be moved back inside the form, allowing events within them to once again properly fire.

Comment: I put this piece of script block into my page [XSP source]. But now the pop up itself is not coming... I am using Notes 8.5.2., Is it any necessary settings to be set in our Xpage property?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do this server side, here's an example of a button that toggles read/edit mode:

```
var comp = getComponent("inputText1");
if (comp && !comp.isReadonly()) {
    comp.setReadonly(true);
}else if (comp && comp.isReadonly()) {
    comp.setReadonly(false);
}
```

Take a look at [this site](http://www.openntf.org/xspext/xpages%20extension%20library%20documentation.nsf/xpages-doc/Controls.html) to see all the properties for all of the components that you can interact with via SSJS.

Comment: Actually I am using this element within dojo dijit.dialog., So server side script needs to update a corresponding item...

Comment: That's precisely what partial refresh events are for. Define the event as server side, include a call to set the component's readonly attribute to false (per Keith's suggestion), and set the refresh ID of the event to be any container which includes the field. NOTE: even if you could toggle the readonly attribute client side, that would still be the wrong approach if you're hoping to store any data entered in the field; the server would still consider the component to be read only, and would therefore ignore any value posted for that field.

Comment: @TimTripcony: Yes Tim I have already tried the Partial refresh for that field... please view the question once again... (I have changed)

Comment: Maybe use a viewscope var to control the readonly property? So in the event handler requestScope.setEditable = true and in the field readonly property #{javascript: return requestScope.containsKey("setEditable")} ?

Answer (score 0):

By creating the field using 
<xp:inputText id="read" readonly="true"></xp:inputText>

the server creates a <SPAN Tag - which cannot be converted into a text field

<span id="view:_id1:inputText1"></span>

In 8.5.3 you would go to All properties on the field and add an Attribute of READONLY with a value of True

This would create the following markup

```
<xp:inputText id="read" defaultValue="Marky">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="READONLY" value="true"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:inputText>
```

In versions prior to R8.5.3 you can add the READONLY attribute to the field programmatically on the onClientLoad event of the page using

dojo.attr("#{id:read}", "READONLY", "true");

Here's the markup

```
<xp:inputText id="read" defaultValue="Marky">

</xp:inputText>

<xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.attr("#{id:read}", "READONLY", "true");]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

THEN once you have create the field on the form correctly you can make it editable by using

document.getElementById("#{id:read}").removeAttribute('readOnly');

Comment: In Inputbox <xp:inputText id="read" readonly="true"></xp:inputText> Please try with this it is not working

Comment: The server is creating a SPAN when displayed <span id="view:_id1:read"></span> - so you cannot use this method if you want to edit the field in the web page - I will provide a better answer now I understand the problem